# https on macos using openssl CA certificate as trusted

Tags: macos, go, ssl, safari, openssl

Inspired from this [github](https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309) I am trying to make a https connection to a macos big sur(11.1)

I keep getting:

> "Safari Can't Open the Page "mydomain.com" because Safari can't
> establish a secure connection to the server "mydomain.com"

Note you need [openssl from brew](https://blog.lukaskukacka.com/ios/2020/09/10/ios13-macos1015-generating-self-signed-certificates.html)

1.Create [rootKey](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204932)

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out rootCA.key
```

2.Create root [certificate](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176)

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 825 \
    -key rootCA.key \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyDomain, Inc./CN=mydomain.com" \
    -addext "extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth" \
    -out rootCA.crt
```

3.Create domain certificate

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out mydomain.com.key
```

4.Create Certificate Request

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl req \
-key mydomain.com.key \
-subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=Mydomain, Inc./CN=mydomain.com" \
-addext "subjectAltName = IP:<x.x.x.x>,DNS:mydomain.com" \
-out mydomain.com.csr
```

5.Generate certificate using CA Root certificate

```
openssl x509 -req -in mydoamin.com.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out mydomain.com.crt -days 825 -sha256
```

6.Add Certificate Authority to Keychain - on the machine connecting via Safari(just use the same machine)

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain rootCA.crt
```

Sample go code - remember if you have firewall turned on, you need to give permission to incomming connection in settings/Security & Privacy "Firewall Options..." allow :

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":443",
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        TLSConfig:    tlsConfig(),
    }

    //// Having this does not change anything but just showing.
    //// go get -u golang.org/x/net/http2
    //if err := http2.ConfigureServer(server, nil); err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal(err)
    //}

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Protocol: %s", r.Proto)))
    })

    if err := server.ListenAndServeTLS("", ""); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func tlsConfig() *tls.Config {
    crt, err := ioutil.ReadFile("mydomain.com.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("mydomain.com.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(crt, key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        ServerName:   "mydomain.com",
    }
}
```

Go code writes:

```
tls: client using inappropriate protocol fallback
```

Comment: Step "6.Add Certificate Authority to Keychain" has huge security implications and probably there are other ways to obtain the end goal, but PKI infrastructure cannot be explained in one stack overflow answer. So let's take a step back: what is your end goal? Why do you want to use TLS certs at all? If you want to test on localhost, you don't need them.

Comment: Hi @marco.m Thanks, I have different domains sites I want to test over https and was hoping to be able just to distribute the rootCA certificate to the developer machines. Hope it makes sense, but basically it is for testing https sites.